# In Perl, what is the difference between if (%hash) and if (defined %hash)?

Tags: perl, hash

What is difference between `if (%hash)` and `if (defined %hash)`?

```
my %hash ;

if ( %hash) { 

  print "defined "; 
}

if (defined %hash)  { 
  print "defined ";
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [perldoc -f defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html):

> Use of "`defined`" on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is
>      deprecated.  It used to report whether memory for that
>      aggregate has ever been allocated.  This behavior may disappear
>      in future versions of Perl.  You should instead use a simple
>      test for size:
>
> ```
>   if (@an_array) { print "has array elements\n" }
>   if (%a_hash)   { print "has hash members\n"   }
> ```

Comment: Before 5.8.3 there was a problem with tied hashes in scalar context.  They would usually return 0.  If you're writing code for pre-5.8.3 use `if( keys %hash )`  http://perldoc.perl.org/perl583delta.html#Core-Enhancements